# Historical Black Sea oceanographic data

Tags: data-request, noaa, climate, oceanographic, meteorology

I'm looking for a data set of historical oceanographic data for the Black Sea, specifically wave heights and sea surface temperature.  NOAA keeps a history archive at ftp://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/history/waves/ and the README ftp://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/history/waves/README claims that the files where `GRIDID` =  `glo_30m - The 30 arc-minute global grid is global` is global data.  However it's not truly global; it's for oceans, and it does not contain the Black Sea.

Is there a resource for historical oceanographic data for the Black Sea?

This is a screen shot of what the `glo_30m' actually covers
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

European data can be obtained from ECMWF at http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/interim-full-daily/levtype=sfc/ and they have an API https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/WEBAPI/Python+ERA-interim+examples